# HTTP request isn't working in another place

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why my code doesn't work in localhost or cpanel host. It's just working in w3schools code editor.

In another host it just sends a bad request that can't get the answer.

```js
function init() {
  url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/js/ajax_info.txt';
  delay = '1000';
  setInterval(
    function() {
      get_data(url);
    }, delay);
}

function get_data(url) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(url);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      alert(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="init()">Get Data</button>
```

Comment: what http server are you using in "another place"? What errors are you seeing in the developer tools console? The URL you are retrieving doesn't allow CORS - so, that could be one problem

Comment: apache , simple php's cpanel host and brower without webserver

Comment: I asked 2 questions ... the important one was about errors in the browser console, which you will clearly have with that code

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.w3schools.com/js/ajax_info.txt' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: see, it's a CORS error - your website can't access data from www.w3schools.com due to the lack of CORS headers - the fact that origin is null means you're not even using a http server - which you did say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Is web server I use an other host and it's worked .